# Postgres order by difference

Tags: postgresql

I am comparing query result set between PostgreSql 9.6 and PostgreSql 12 version. Noticed a very strange behavior in query result. Running below query from psql

```
SELECT current_database(),table_name
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
   AND table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
ORDER BY table_name;
```

PostgreSql 9.6 Output

```
current_database |          table_name          
------------------+------------------------------
mydb              |key_request_sum
mydb              |key_req_user
```

PostgreSql 12 output

```
current_database  |          table_name          
------------------+------------------------------    
mydb              |key_req_user
mydb              |key_request_sum
```

This is strange to see the different output for same query for different version. please suggest what to change in query to make Postgres 12 result same as 9.6

Comment: This is a guess, as I don't have an instance of 9.6 handy, but the datatype in 12 is "name."  Is it possible it was text/varchar in V9?  I don't know how sorting works for the name datatype.  If you test a raw sort you will see it works as expected:  `select * from (values ('key_request_sum'), ('key_req_user')) t (table_name) order by 1`

Comment: I have to admit...  I've messed around with this a little, and I'm absolutely baffled.  If I create a table as text, text and insert this query, the sort works fine.  In all other scenarios it does not.  What a head scratcher.

Comment: Are both versions on same machine?  1) If so best bet is the databases have different character sets. If not 1)  or different `glibc`, see [Locale data changes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes).

Comment: Yes .. both versions are on different  machines but 12 is created with 9.6 pg_dump.. will check on characterset.

Comment: Also provide OS and version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 9.6 version, you can have it collate by the locality that worked in the days before UTF finally got fixed to the point of being usable:

```
create table key_req_user ();
create table key_request_user ();

select current_database(), table_name, pg_typeof(table_name)
  from information_schema.tables
 where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
   and table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
 order by table_name collate "en_US.utf8";
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a8a80b9a114e91902fdd2b6f3bda68df)*